# HTTP restriction: oversized cookie

Tags: http, cookies, heroku

I recently deployed my application on heroku and I am getting a 502 error with description : `HTTP restriction: oversized cookie`

Found on Heroku :

> Oversized cookies
>
> The cookie in the response will be too large to be used again in a request to the Heroku router or SSL endpoints.

I have no idea on how to overcome this. I tried lots of advices from [Heroku troubleshooting page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/troubleshooting) without success.

Also everything works fine locally (setting a Python virtual environment and running `foreman start`).

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution by just looking at the response headers locally using Chrome devtools. I realized that Flask sessions are built on top of cookies which caused the oversizing issue ([see here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#sessions)). I just got rid of it and now everything works fine.